# How to append elements to a specific list position?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What am I trying to do?
I want to put multiple elements to the same position in a list without discarding the previously appended ones.

I know that if `mylist.append("something")`is used, the appended elements will be added every time to the end of the list.

What I want it's something like this `mylist[i].append("something")`.
Of course that doesn't work, but it's just the idea.

I tried to append a list to another list, but that didn't work neither because the append function can't handle lists.

Is there any way to append stuff to a specific zone in a list?

Comment: Yes, that topic is similar. I searched pretty much before posting and also It didn't showed up when asking, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use list slicing and concatenation as:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8]
new_lst = [4, 5]
position = 3
combined_lst = lst[:position] + new_lst + lst[position:]
```

Comment: Oh, so basically I create a new list. :D
That will work, thank you!